# Connect to particular API based on environment

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api

I have an AngularJS application that talks to a NodeJS backend. I have recently just hard-coded in the API address in my front-end as there has only been one environment (i.e. my development environment has been the same as my production environment).

However, as the project has expanded, I now have three environments: development, staging and production.

My development and staging environments talk to the same API (let's say dev.fooapi.com), but my production environment should be talking to a different API (let's say prod.fooapi.com).

My question is: what are some 'elegant' (I put this in quotes because who is to say what is elegant and what isn't) ways of achieving this in my application? I currently have a string placeholder in my source files that looks like 'API_PLACEHOLDER' and a Grunt task that performs a string replace anywhere in my codebase where it matches that string. Obviously this isn't ideal because the files where these placeholders are substituted are source controlled, and I don't really want to do a string replace and then accidentally commit some code that has hard coded developer API addresses because that will break in production.

Extra information: I do make use of Grunt in my application, I deploy to Windows (can't be changed, unfortunately), I use Git for source control and I do builds/deployment using Bamboo.

More than happy to answer any other questions about my issue.

Note: I need to substitute config values not only for my front end but also the back end (i.e. when I start my node server I want the port that it starts on to be configurable.

Thanks!

Comment: An environment variable in the back-end can tell the back-end what Javascript variable to put into each page so the front-end can use that JS variable to know what api DNS name to use.  Or you can code the front-end to check for such variable and, if not found, it will use the production environment.  If found, it will use whatever is there.

Comment: @jfriend00 - how does the front-end know what the environment variable in the back end is? Sounds like a chicken-and-egg problem to me.

Comment: If you read again, I said the back-end puts a JS variable in every page that indicates what to use.  Because the JS variable is in the page, it's available to the front-end JS.

Comment: How would the back-end put Javascript in every page? It's an Angular application.

Comment: I don't know Angular myself, but don't you have some ability to modify a page on the server before it's sent to the client to inject a script tag or to modify a variable's value?  It's nodejs on the back-end so any of the template rendering engines can do that.

Comment: The back-end doesn't have the ability to modify pages on the front-end. They are completely separate. The back-end purely serves as an API endpoint. The front-end is purely a statically served site (i.e. all it is is html/js/css). The only interaction between the front-end and the back-end are RESTful requests.

Comment: Where do your pages come from?  Where does the HTML come from?  Where does the Javascript come from?  It comes from a back-end somewhere.  They are being served by a web server somewhere.

Comment: They're served up as static resources by a web server. Having the web server modify those files when it's only job is to serve static files seems like a horrible hack job. Not to mention that my web server and my API server are not located on the same machine.

Comment: Well, you didn't say that in your question.  Usually people using a node.js use for both serving files and for things like API.  That's what I assumed.  If you're only serving static files, then you can ignore my suggestion.  There's not going to be any automatic solution to this if you're not going to modify the files sent to the browser.  The client simply has no way to know what to do if you're not going to put that info in at least one files sent to the browser.

Comment: If your actual setup here is one set of statically served files that will not be modified in any way to indicate which API server to use and three separate API servers (only one of which should be used), then you should put that info in your question because it's incredibly important to the question.

Comment: I apologise for the confusion, but I initially thought you were meeting me with hostility when I suggested that your suggestion might not be the best fit for me. I will update my original question and I thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: I've modified my application to be served from my Node server, but I'm still failing to see what the best way would be to dynamically have the server tell the front end what address it has and what port to connect on. Any ideas?

Comment: If your node server is now on the same host as the HTML files are served from, then the front-end can just examine `window.location.hostname` to see where it came from and use that host for the API request.  If your node server is not using the same port the files were served from, then there is no magic sauce for communicating a port to the front-end other than have the server embed that knowledge in a script file somehow or making your scripts just "know" which port to use with which host (e.g. coding that knowledge into your front-end scripts).

Comment: There are definitely other solutions - I am writing up my own answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [gulp-ng-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-config)  which allows dynamically generated angular constants to be added to my application based off the node environment variable.

In the docs from link above is an example of supply a different api url to front end app, I'm sure there is a grunt version, in fact [grunt-ng-config](https://github.com/werk85/grunt-ng-constant) looks like the equivalent. The values config option takes a function where you can return something based on the node environment variable

Comment: That looks great! My only question is that since it does a string replace in the modules it touches, and the modules that it touches are source controlled, it will flag those files as changed and I don't want to commit the results as that will break production and staging builds. How would I go about dealing with this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by it does a string replace on the modules it touches. I have added the name of the file it creates to my gitignore list, that's all I have had to do source control wise

Comment: A string replace is just taking a pattern and replacing it with something else :)

Comment: Ok well I'm not hitting any issues with source control. The resulting module file it generates I have in my gitignore list. Im not committing the final concatenated/minified source either